# Multidimensional and associative array (hash) via POST in Perl/Catalyst

Tags: perl, forms, post, webforms, catalyst

In PHP, I would do this to get 'points' as an multidimensional array.

```
<input type"text" name="points[0][1]" />
<input type"text" name="points[0][2]" />
<input type"text" name="points[1][1]" />
<input type"text" name="points[2][2]" />
```

Or if I wanted to get 'point' as an associative array:

```
<input type"text" name="point[x_axis]" />
<input type"text" name="point[y_axis]" />
```

What is the Catalyst/Perl equivalent for such things?
How can I get these through $c->req->params ??

Comment: I can't wait to send `name="points[100000000]"` to a PHP script! or is there a check for that?

Comment: @ikegami since all arrays in PHP are secretly (ordered) associative arrays, it's more harmless than it looks — you get an array with one pair in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't provided out-of-the-box — Catalyst doesn't do any mapping on param names, and maps the values to either scalars if they appear once, or arrayrefs if they appear multiple times. However there's a request trait you can apply, [Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::Params::Hashed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::Params::Hashed) that adds `hashed_params`, `hashed_query_params`, and `hashed_body_params` methods to `$c->request` that behave in pretty much the way you want.